# sql count function is not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to count all  rows  with related query . but the 'Count' function is not  working correctly and  gives invalid number.

I execute the query without  Count  function and the row count is correct .

First Query :

```
   SELECT  

    *
    from [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Cards Cards
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Products Products ON Cards.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Subjects Subjects ON Products.SubjectID = Subjects.SubjectID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.CardStatusTypes CardStatusTypes ON Cards.CardStatusTypeID = CardStatusTypes.ID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Applications Applications ON Products.ApplicationID = Applications.ApplicationID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Branches Branches ON Applications.DeliverBranchID = Branches.ID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.ApplicationPersons ApplicationPersons ON Applications.ApplicationID = ApplicationPersons.ApplicationID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.ApplicationOrganizations ApplicationOrganizations on Applications.ApplicationID=ApplicationOrganizations.ApplicationID
    inner join [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Certificates Certificates on Products.ProductID = Certificates.ProductID 
    inner join [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.CertificateStatusHistory CertificateStatusHistory on Certificates.CertificateID = CertificateStatusHistory.CertificateID 
    inner join [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.CertificateStatusTypes CertificateStatusTypes on CertificateStatusHistory.StatusTypeID = CertificateStatusTypes.ID
    WHERE Personalized <> '' and Certificates.CertificateTypeID = 2 and 
    (CardStatusTypes.ID = 10 or CardStatusTypes.ID = 101 or CardStatusTypes.ID = 3)  and CertificateStatusTypes.Id = 1
    and Personalized >= '2011-01-01' and Personalized < '2019-01-01'
```

After execution of this query at the  right of the bottom  shows count of rows  displayed  in grid. It is 45652 for example .

But when I try the same  query with  'count' function  it displays  111510
and it didn't change even I change the  periods.
The Query :

```
SELECT  

    count(*)

    from [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Cards Cards
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Products Products ON Cards.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Subjects Subjects ON Products.SubjectID = Subjects.SubjectID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.CardStatusTypes CardStatusTypes ON Cards.CardStatusTypeID = CardStatusTypes.ID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Applications Applications ON Products.ApplicationID = Applications.ApplicationID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Branches Branches ON Applications.DeliverBranchID = Branches.ID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.ApplicationPersons ApplicationPersons ON Applications.ApplicationID = ApplicationPersons.ApplicationID 
    inner JOIN [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.ApplicationOrganizations ApplicationOrganizations on Applications.ApplicationID=ApplicationOrganizations.ApplicationID
    inner join [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.Certificates Certificates on Products.ProductID = Certificates.ProductID 
    inner join [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.CertificateStatusHistory CertificateStatusHistory on Certificates.CertificateID = CertificateStatusHistory.CertificateID 
    inner join [db_ip].[DBNAME].dbo.CertificateStatusTypes CertificateStatusTypes on CertificateStatusHistory.StatusTypeID = CertificateStatusTypes.ID
    WHERE Personalized <> '' and Certificates.CertificateTypeID = 2 and 
    (CardStatusTypes.ID = 10 or CardStatusTypes.ID = 101 or CardStatusTypes.ID = 3)  and CertificateStatusTypes.Id = 1
    and Personalized >= '2011-01-01' and Personalized < '2019-01-01'
```

[image: Here is the image]

[image: The correct Image]
These queries are  going to linked servers.
What is the reason of this problem  ?

Comment: "shows rows displayed in the grid" What grid? What is the client? Is there a max number of rows that your client will pull (45652 does seem pretty arbitrary, but it's worth asking). I can't imagine any other scenario that would cause that to be wrong. I would trust the `count(*)` number of the number reported by the client, at any rate.

Comment: How do you "know" one is correct and the other is not?

Comment: After the first query, without the `count(*)`, enter `Select @@ROWCOUNT` and see what you get.

Comment: @JNevill The client is  SSMS. We grouped it by days but it also  shows incorrect result. We did it for daily.

Comment: @Andrew Because    (select * from) this query displays the rows for counting.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  one row  affected )

Comment: What happens when you paste both queries into the same SSMS window and execute them in one go?

Comment: @GSerg The same thing. One of hem shows   111510, other  45652.

Comment: And you have only these two queries in that code pane, not [anything else](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ssms-query-returns-wrong-row-count-until-clicking-in-results-area#post-1314592)?

Comment: @Freeedy, Yes, 1 row affected that's in your `Messages` pane, but what is the # from the `Select @@ROWCOUNT` statement in the `Results` pane?

Comment: @WEI_DBA the same  . 1

Comment: @GSerg screenshots are added.

Comment: Not that it may make any difference regarding the row counts. Since you are specifying a date range, remove `Personalized <> ''` and change this `(CardStatusTypes.ID = 10 or CardStatusTypes.ID = 101 or CardStatusTypes.ID = 3)` to `CardStatusTypes.ID IN (10,101,3)`. Might make better performance and easier to read.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I get the same results.  May it  related to the  linked servers? Because, all those tables are  hosted  in linked server.